# Javascript srt.IndexOf() return -1 (but include)

Tags: javascript, string, indexof

When I was using the indexOf() functions , it return the "-1" . But I know that "the string include that which is I try to found string".

Example :

```
"SANAYİ VE TİCARET LİMİTED ŞİRKETİ".toLowerCase().indexOf("şirket".toLowerCase())
```

return -1

Solution 1:

```
str = "SANAYİ VE TİCARET LİMİTED ŞİRKETİ"    
var letters = { "İ": "i", "I": "ı", "Ş": "ş", "Ğ": "ğ", "Ü": "ü", "Ö": "ö", "Ç": "ç" };    
str = str.replace(/(([İIŞĞÜÇÖ]))/g, function(letter){ return letters[letter]; })


var index = str.toLowerCase().indexOf("şirket".toLowerCase())
```

Solution 2:

```
"SANAYİ VE TİCARET LİMİTED ŞİRKETİ".toLocaleLowerCase('tr').indexOf("şirket".toLocaleLowerCase('tr'))
```

Comment: You should probably use an encoding library, because the lowercase output does not equal what you have. For example. this `İ` gets transformed to`i̇` instead of `i`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already mentioned in the other answers, localized strings need to be handled differently.

If you know for sure in which language the strings are, you can use the locale versions of [toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) and [toUpperCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase), i.e., [toLocaleLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLocaleLowerCase) and [toLocaleUpperCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLocaleUpperCase) respectively.

Assuming that the strings are in Turkish language, pass the ISO code parameter `'tr'` to the function `toLocaleLowerCase()`:

Therefore

```
"SANAYİ VE TİCARET LİMİTED ŞİRKETİ".toLowerCase().indexOf("şirket".toLowerCase())
```

returns indeed `-1`

but

```
"SANAYİ VE TİCARET LİMİTED ŞİRKETİ".toLocaleLowerCase('tr').indexOf("şirket".toLocaleLowerCase('tr'))
```

returns correctly: `26`

HTH...

Answer (score 2):

Working with localised strings can be tricky due to non-english characters.

`"SANAYİ VE TİCARET LİMİTED ŞİRKETİ".toLowerCase()` returns `"sanayi̇ ve ti̇caret li̇mi̇ted şi̇rketi̇"`.

`"SANAYİ VE TİCARET LİMİTED ŞİRKETİ".toLowerCase().indexOf("şi̇rket".toLowerCase())` (note "şi̇rket" instead of "şirket") returns `30`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you have two different words `ŞİRKETİ` which is `şi̇rketi̇` which is not `şirket`. Take a look on different `i̇` and `i`

Answer (score 0):

```
var letters = { "İ": "i", "I": "ı", "Ş": "ş", "Ğ": "ğ", "Ü": "ü", "Ö": "ö", "Ç": "ç" };
str = str.replace(/(([İIŞĞÜÇÖ]))/g, function(letter){ return letters[letter]; })
```

it's run for me